# Scramble a 1000-size array in python

Tags: python, random

In Python, what is the most scrambling 1000-size array which have 0 to 9999 number in each index. 
Like suffling music when we are using streaming service.

Comment: You wish to shuffle a list order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shuffle function (shuffles in place):

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(List_to_shuffle)
```